# SP 2013: OOTB Custom form deletes itself

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I’m using SP 2013 to create custom task forms, but also editing the aspx code to make some columns read only, add comments, etc. Within SPD, in --> List and Libraries – Tasks – Forms, I create three new edit forms. AAA_Abcdefgh111.aspx, AAA_Abcdefgh112.aspx, AAA_Abcdefgh113.aspx. Each used for a separate task in a workflow.

I then custom edit these forms for read only columns, etc.

Once saved and I preview in browser, guaranteed one of the three forms show in IE as blank. Upon reviewing the aspx code I see there is nothing within the `<ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>`. Its as shown = blank. When place back the missing aspx code (saved to external file), the form in question works and one of the other three forms becomes blank.

What the @%$#!!

Comment: After the form saw the name you've given to it, it probably just went "ah, f%$# it!"

Answer (score 0):

I think I sorted this out.

I was copying a created custom form and then editing it to make another custom form. I think each custom form needs to be generated by SPD, then you can edit the form. Each one must have a unique GUID or something. SP must have seen all the copied custom forms as one odd package. Thus when I saved an edit, some other edit got erased….. at least that’s what I can figure. - Regards